# Syntax Error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, syntax-error, pyqt4

Configuring the encoding for cp1252 to configure some sequences like "~ '^", for example when I put in coding: utf-8 the strings with text formatting error, I already tested with "latin-1" and the same error continues.

If I edit "cp1252" to "cp1252" again, I can open it normally, but when I close and later open the file, the error message comes back.
Someone knows how to solve the following error, it always appears that I will execute the main script file.
`SyntaxError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 45: character maps to <undefined>`

```
# coding: cp1252

import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from ytconsole import *

self.msgt2 =QMessageBox()
self.msgt2.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
self.msgt2.setWindowTitle('Python Youtube Downloader') -->[Here is the problem] line 353
self.msgt2.setText("{} arquivos MP4 foram baixados, salvos na Área de Trabalho".format(int(l)))``
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.15

Comment: Here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/wpxF4h8

Comment: `"{} arquivos MP4 foram baixados, salvos na Área de Trabalho".decode('cp1252')` raises the `UnicodeDecodeError`, so you can't have that string in your file if the source code encoding is cp1252.  UTF-8 is generally a better choice.  That said, I don't know whether PyQT4 expects to receive unicode or bytes.